# int treated as `self' in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to build a simple server that dispatches requests depending on their path. So I wrote the following code:

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
import json
import socket

class Handler:
    """处理对应资源的请求"""
    def __init__(self, dispatcher):
        self.dispatcher = dispatcher

    def handle(self):
        """根据dispatcher解析出来的path，调用对应的方法"""
        command = 'do_' + self.dispatcher.command
        print(command)
        if not hasattr(self, command):
            return;

        method = getattr(self, command)
        method(self)

    def do_GET(self):
        response = {
            'message': 'message'
        }
        dispatcher.protocol_version = 'HTTP/1.1'
        dispatcher.send_response(200, 'OK')
        dispatcher.send_header('Content-type', 'text/plain')
        dispatcher.wfile.write(bytes(json.dumps(response), 'utf-8'))

class dispatcher(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    """
    根据url的不同分发请求
    """
    def handle_one_request(self):
        try:
            self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
            if len(self.raw_requestline) > 65536:
                self.requestline = ''
                self.request_version = ''
                self.command = ''
                self.send_error(HTTPStatus.REQUEST_URI_TOO_LONG)
                return
            if not self.raw_requestline:
                self.close_connection = True
                return
            if not self.parse_request():
                # An error code has been sent, just exit
                return
            print(self.command)
            print(self.path)
            if self.path.startswith('/wrong'):
                Handler(self).handle()
            self.wfile.flush() #actually send the response if not already done.
        except socket.timeout as e:
            #a read or a write timed out.  Discard this connection
            self.log_error("Request timed out: %r", e)
            self.close_connection = True
            return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = HTTPServer(('', 8080), dispatcher)
    server.serve_forever()
```

The `dispatcher` will parse the incoming request and get the path so that it can decide which handler to call(though there is only one here for now).

In the `handler` class, it will call corresponding method based on the http method. In the `do_GET` method, it will call some methods in the dispatcher and that's where things go wrong.

When I ran this program and execute `curl http://localhost:8080/wrong`, I had the following exception:

```
GET
/wrong
do_GET
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 50072)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 313, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 341, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 354, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socketserver.py", line 681, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/server.py", line 422, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "hello.py", line 51, in handle_one_request
    Handler(self).handle()
  File "hello.py", line 18, in handle
    method()
  File "hello.py", line 25, in do_GET
    dispatcher.send_response(200, 'OK')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/server.py", line 487, in send_response
    self.log_request(code)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'log_request'
----------------------------------------
```

`log_request` is defined as follows in the super class of `dispatcher`:

```
def log_request(self, code='-', size='-'):
    # blablabla
```

and it is called in dispatcher.send_response.

I guess the problem is that the `200` is treated as `self` by the interpreter.

If my guess is right, why is this happening?

If not, what causes this exception?

I know this question is still in the grammar level, but I'd appreciate it if someone can help me.

Comment: within `do_GET` you're using `dispatcher` instead of `self.dispatcher` :)

Comment: @Wolph thanks, problem solved. Never gonna to instantiate object with the same name of class again :D

Comment: @Charles: This is part of the reason why [PEP8 recommends the CapWords convention for class names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names) (and nothing else); if the class is `Dispatcher`, then a variable named `dispatcher` isn't a problem, whether or not it's on `self`.